# Double List in NavigationView [Swift]

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, ios-navigationview, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to fit two categories of an item on two different list, named 'Wide-Field' and 'Deep-Sky', however I want the second list to be **below** the first.

I was **expecting** it to look something like this:

[image]

However, instead it splits the screen in half and I get this result:

[image]

My current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(Photographs.wideFieldPhotos, id: \.self) { key in
                        HStack {
                            PhotographRow(photo: key)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Wide-Field")
                List {
                    ForEach(Photographs.deepSkyPhotos, id: \.self) { key in
                        HStack {
                            PhotographRow(photo: key)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Deep-Sky")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want instead *one* List with *two* Sections, like

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Wide-Field").font(.largeTitle)) {
                ForEach(Photographs.wideFieldPhotos, id: \.self) { key in
                    HStack {
                        PhotographRow(photo: key)
                    }
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("Deep-Sky").font(.largeTitle)) {
                ForEach(Photographs.deepSkyPhotos, id: \.self) { key in
                    HStack {
                        PhotographRow(photo: key)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```